# How do you actually parse values in YAML in Java?

Tags: java, parsing, yaml

I have a YAML file that I'm using as sort of a config file. It ooks like this,

```
tests:
    - category: some_category
      test:
          - name: hello
            key1: value1
            key2: value2

          - name: hithere
            key1: value1
            key2: value2
```

I want to do something like this:

```
for all tests as test:
  print test.name + test.key1
```

I have looked at JYaml and SnakeYaml but all they seem to do is map from YAML to Java objects. Is YAML not the right job for this? Is there a simple way to achieve this? all I need is to iterate through and get the values of each, kind of like a DOM traversal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I figured it out. I am using YamlBeans, which provides methods for this: https://github.com/EsotericSoftware/yamlbeans

Comment: SnakeYAML can parse it with 2 lines:
Yaml yaml = new Yaml();
yaml.load(document);

What are the methods in YamlBeams which are not available in SnakeYAML ?